# Problems in UART communication between ESP32 and STM32

Tags: stm32, microcontroller, esp32, uart

I have a problem with the UART communication between an ESP32 and a STM32. Everything is working fine until I hardreset the ESP32 then I see a frame error on RX and in TX a shift in the response.
response. As soon as I hardreset the STM32 then everything works again and I see the same output as input. Can someone
help me?

```
#include "main.h"


#include "ProductMain.h"
#include <string.h>

#include "DebugOutput.h"

#include "GUI.h"



uint8_t UART7_rxBuffer[2] = {0};
uint8_t pass1 = 99;

uint8_t rfidDetected = 0;


SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart7;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;


void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);
static void MX_UART7_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);

char spi_buf ='A';

int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();


  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_UART7_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();

  Product_init();


  HAL_UART_Receive_IT (&huart7, UART7_rxBuffer, 2);
  HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart7, UART7_rxBuffer, 2);

  while (1)
  {
      Product_loop(pass1);

  }

}


void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

 
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);

  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 192;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV8;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  HAL_RCC_MCOConfig(RCC_MCO1, RCC_MCO1SOURCE_PLLCLK, RCC_MCODIV_1);
}


static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{


  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_4;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }


}


static void MX_UART7_Init(void)
{


  huart7.Instance = UART7;
  huart7.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart7.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart7.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart7.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart7.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart7.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart7.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart7) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }


}


static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{


  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }


}


static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};


  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET);


  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port, SPI1_CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);


  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, DISPLAY_RESET_Pin|DISPLAY_DATA_CMD_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);


  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);


  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = SPI1_CS_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(SPI1_CS_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);


  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF0_MCO;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);


  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = DISPLAY_RESET_Pin|DISPLAY_DATA_CMD_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = DISPLAY_BUSY_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(DISPLAY_BUSY_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}



void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{

    HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart7, UART7_rxBuffer, 2);
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart7, UART7_rxBuffer, 2);

}


void Error_Handler(void)
{

  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }

}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT

void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{

}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Best regards

[Framing Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnHDu.jpg)

[Shift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSdYq.jpg)

Comment: Please show your code and in particular how you handle frame errors, which are to be expected when the ESP32 is reset.

Comment: Thx Codo. I was thinking about handling frame erros as well, currently i'm not doing any. Can you please support me here further?

Comment: Meanwhile i tried to use HAL_UART_ErrorCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart), but even though when i put inside HAL_UART_Abort(&huart7) or HAL_UART_AbortReceive(&huart7) i can not prevent the buffer of getting filled... What I'm doing wrong here? The Null or "\0" is getting into my buffer of UART7_rxBuffer[0]...

Comment: Not so clean but works, any recommendation to improve this? What's your opinion @Codo void HAL_UART_ErrorCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
  HAL_UART_Abort_IT(&huart7);
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT (&huart7, UART7_rxBuffer, 3);
  HAL_UART_Transmit_IT (&huart7, UART7_rxBuffer, 3);
}

Comment: That's a start. Most likely you also need error detection at a higher level so you can distinguish garbage (like the null bytes) and communication errors from good data.